# Complex Where statement

Tags: sql, where-clause

I've got a simple query as example:

```
Select 
    test_table.country,
    test_table.postcode
From test_table
Where
    test_table.country Like 'B%'
    Or
    test_table.postcode Like '1%'
```

Which lists all countries starting with letter B and any postcode, or all counrtries with postcodes starting with 1.
I want to exclude all countries starting with 'C' if their postcode starts with '1'

```
test_table.country Not Like 'C%' And test_table.postcode Not Like '1%'
```

How do I achieve it without ruining previous queries?

Comment: Why you can‘t use the query?

Comment: If I use it, it will remove all postcodes starting with 1 but I want only C% countries to have it removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using parentheses can matter.
Certainly when using `OR` in combination with `AND`.

```
Select 
  t.country,
  t.postcode
From test_table As t
Where
  (   
      (t.country Not Like 'B%' And t.country Not Like 'C%') 
   Or (t.country Like 'C%' And t.postcode Like '1%')
  )
```

**Extra Test based on comment**

> ```
> create table countries (
>  ctry_code char(2) primary key not null, 
>  country_name varchar(30) not null
> )
>
> create table postcodes (
>  ctry_code char(2) not null,
>  postcode varchar(8) not null, 
>  primary key (ctry_code, postcode), 
>  foreign key (ctry_code) references countries(ctry_code)
> )
>
> insert into countries (ctry_code, country_name) values
>   ('BE', 'Belgium')
> , ('BG', 'Bulgaria')
> , ('ES', 'Spain')
> , ('LS', 'Lesotho')
> , ('PT', 'Portugal')
> , ('IT', 'Italy')
>
> insert into postcodes (ctry_code, postcode) values
>   ('BE', '1111'), ('BG', '1112'), ('ES', '1113'), ('LS', '1114')
> , ('PT', '1115'), ('IT', '1116')
> , ('BE', '2221'), ('BG', '2222'), ('ES', '2223'), ('LS', '2224')
> , ('PT', '2225'), ('IT', '2226')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT country_name, post.ctry_code, postcode
> FROM postcodes AS post
> JOIN countries AS ctry 
>   ON ctry.ctry_code = post.ctry_code
> WHERE ( country_name NOT IN ('Belgium', 'Spain', 'Portugal')
>         AND (country_name NOT IN ('Italy') 
>              OR (country_name IN ('Italy') AND postcode LIKE '1%'))
>       )
> ORDER BY country_name, post.ctry_code;
> ```
>
> ```
> country_name | ctry_code | postcode
> :----------- | :-------- | :-------
> Bulgaria     | BG        | 1112    
> Bulgaria     | BG        | 2222    
> Italy        | IT        | 1116    
> Lesotho      | LS        | 1114    
> Lesotho      | LS        | 2224
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b5f3ec64dde11c90006838bc7a96c5f2)*

Comment: Thanks, was a bad example from me. I've got a query as follows:
Where 
    test_table.country <> 'Belgium'
and test_table.country <> 'Bulgaria'
and test_table.country <> 'Spain'
and test_table.country <> 'Portugal'

And I also need to add "and test_table.country <> 'Italy' and table.postcode Like '1%' but only to apply for Italy, not rest of the countries.
Would this work?
Where 
    (test_table.country <> 'Belgium'
and test_table.country <> 'Bulgaria'
and test_table.country <> 'Spain'
and test_table.country <> 'Portugal'
and (test_table.country <> 'Italy' and Not like '5%'))

Comment: @Jedas See extra in updated answer. Something like that? Or what's wrong?

Comment: @LukStorms, I'll humbly change your code since I understand there's a logic failure there. Please, forgive me, and revise ASAP :-) Congrats.

Comment: Heh, the change gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, the way I've got around it is by using criteria:

```
Concat(test_table.country, Left(test_table.postcode,1))<>'Italia5'
```